# Are there sonic faucets?

Tags: star-trek, technology

[Sonic showers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sonic_shower) are of course a well known and accepted technology in Star Trek, perfectly capable of replacing traditional water-based showers or baths (which may still be used recreationally.)

What happens when one only needs to wash one's hands, such as after using the waste extractor or before prepping some non-replicated food?

Are there sonic faucets of some sort, or are traditional soap and water still required?

Canon and/or EU answers are acceptable.

Comment: Part of me keeps wanting to say it's "the fresher" that they use for such tasks, but my searches are coming up blank.

Comment: Related - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89793/how-does-a-sonic-shower-work      Since there are sonic showers, sonic taps/faucets are probably just another outlet on the same pipe system.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like [they wash their hands with water in a sink](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sink).

[image: Image of hands being washed in a sink]

I haven't found any examples using something like a "sonic shower" for hand cleaning.

Comment: I did eventually find an example, albeit from another SE question. In the linked question, the EMH seems to be using something that could be described as a "sonic faucet" to scrub in before surgery (Voy S03E04) https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170842/why-did-the-voyager-doctor-have-to-scrub-in

Comment: @Tronman But as the answer points out, he was malfunctioning, and that could have been part of his delusion.

Comment: Agreed, but irrelevant to my question. Clearly there does exist some sort of wireless hand washing / sterilization technology, even the doctor was imagining that he needed it.